# Extract background scene from video

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

I am working on a video processing project using Qt and opencv. As a processing step I need to extract the background from a video (real time streaming) in which humans pass by. I need to know whether Opencv has inbuilt functions for extracting static objects from a video
?

Comment: Detecting background is hard, especially since some background may _not_ be static at all (e.g. a weathervane or a flag).

Comment: There are some functions in OpenCV, details I don't know. this may be a simple startup : http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html

Comment: I need to track only static pixels since my project doesnt deal with nonstatic backgrounds...

Comment: So, basically, subtract one image from the other. All pixels that are the same are "background".

Comment: yeah I am new to image processing so I didnt really get what you jst mentioned sir..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this OpenCV class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2).

```
cv::Mat original;     // your frame
cv::Mat foreground;   // your foreground
cv::Mat background;   // your background

cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog;

mog.history = 150;            // How many frames should be used for calculation
mog.nShadowDetection = false; // There are a lot of parameters to adjust

mog(original,foreground,0.01);  // Binary foreground saved in "foreground"

mog.getBackgroundImage(background); // Output the current background of the model
```

The class implements the Gaussian mixture model background subtraction described in:

Z.Zivkovic, Improved adaptive Gausian mixture model for background
   subtraction, International Conference Pattern Recognition, UK,
   August, 2004,
   http://www.zoranz.net/Publications/zivkovic2004ICPR.pdf. The code is
   very fast and performs also shadow detection. Number of Gausssian
   components is adapted per pixel.

Comment: Sir I need the background...is there anything similar to this for getting background?

Comment: There's a function called getBackgroundImage(). I changed the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: sir the IDE shows compilation error and says the history and nshadowdetection are protected!!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method and the easy one is to use the median of the previous frames

you can use an update process of the first background image to take into account the new static objects
more sophisticated method like Pinciple Component Analysis- Mixture of Gaussians- Self-organizing Background subtraction and CNN can resolve your problem but are not suitable for streaming unless you are using special hardware FPGA or GPU